# How to make the created JAR file from Maven-WAR plugin into build path

Tags: maven, maven-war-plugin

I have used Maven -war plugin to create a JAR from another reference WAR .Now this JAR is available in the target folder.
My problem is I have to use the class which is available inside the created JAR in target folder but I am unable to get the class from JAR.

Is it possible to make available the created JAR available in the classpath through POM.
My maven WAR plugin as like below.

```
<plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                    <configuration>                     
                        <overlays>
                            <overlay />
                            <overlay>
                                <groupId>test.Vehicle</groupId>
                                <artifactId>test-location</artifactId>
                            </overlay>
                        </overlays>
                        <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>                         
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Comment: If you like to create a separate of the class files within the war module the `<attachClasses>true</attachClasses>` is the correct way. But what you like to achieve by using `groupId`, `artifactId` within the configuration i can not answer, cause those parameters do not exist.

Comment: @khmarbaise thankyou .I have modified my question based on my exact requirement.Can you please help me